# Is it posible to bring up a VM with vagrant but then manage it from WMWare?

Tags: vagrant, vmware, vmware-workstation

I've been reading up on Vagrant, but i can't find anything about whether after creating a VM with vagrant (specifically using a VMWare provider) you can still manage it from the "provider" software (in this case WorkStation or Player).

I would like to bring it up using `vagrant up` and when it finishes provisioning, "release it" from vagrant and manage it from VMWare Workstation. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible with VirtualBox. Vagrant doesn't "capture" the virtual machine in any way, it doesn't need to be "released". Vagrant only keeps some information to identify and manage the box but the box itself is completely under the control of VirtualBox. I don't know how it works with VMWare, but I don't think it's very different though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @axiac is basically correct, but things works slightly different with VMWare, at least I am using VMware Fusion on macos so below is based on my usage.

When you bring up VM with VMWare, the vmx file is created in `.vagrant` folder of your project directory and the VM is not automatically added in the VM listed in VMWare.

Also the VM does not appear in the CLI. so when the VMs are halted and running

```
fhenri@machine:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library$ ./vmrun list
Total running VMs: 0
```

and when I spin up the VM, I will get

```
fhenri@machine:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library$ ./vmrun list
Total running VMs: 2
/Users/fhenri/project/ariba/pws.source/.vagrant/machines/db/vmware_fusion/89e5f21d-7078-44ed-8407-17dcc8c335ee/centos65.vmx
/Users/fhenri/project/ariba/pws.source/.vagrant/machines/app/vmware_fusion/6ee0dc5d-ec17-429c-9fd0-b069bfc0b040/centos65.vmx
```

When you open VMWare GUI, nothing appears in the VM library, if the VM are running, the VM GUI are available, beware that if you close any window form this point, the VM will shutdown (this is a main difference with VirtualBox as vb manages better the process of the VM and the vb process itself) but you can manually add the vmx file to vmware library if you want to later start and manage the VM from vmware itself

Comment: So, if i spin the vm with vagrant, then locate the vmx file (with or without moving the vm related files to another folder) and add it to the VMWare gui, i could manage the vm mainly from wmare as if vagrant was never involved?
Thanks!

Comment: you're right - the vmx file are located in the `.vagrant` folder of your project folder (the folder with the Vagrantfile) then import those files (move them somewhere else if needed) in VMWare and just use VMWare if you're more comfortable - the only vagrant part will probably be the vagrant user (unless you created your box yourself using another main user)

Answer (score 1):

I have this bit in my `vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |v|
   v.gui = true
end
```

When you do `vagrant up`, you should see it in Workstation/Fusion automatically, and control it from there.